# why this is error in node js cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, cluster-computing

Hello i want to learn multi threading in node js. And i'm learning now but i have some trouble about cluster in node js. I found these codes in below.
why these codes give error when i want to go to http://localhost/plumber address ?
thanks...

```js
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
var http = require('http');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log (' Fork %s worker(s) from master', numCPUs);
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }
    cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
        console.log ('worker is running on %s pid', worker.process.pid);
    });
    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker with %s is closed', worker.process.pid);
    });
} else if (cluster.isWorker) {
    var port = 3000;
    console.log('worker (%s) is now listening to http://localhost:%s',
        cluster.worker.process.pid, port);
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        console.log(req.url+cluster.worker.process.pid);
        if(req.url=='/plumber'){
            sleep(10);
            res.end('no write because of error but answer requests');
        }else {
            res.end('cluster' + cluster.worker.process.pid + 'answered');
        }
    }).listen(port,"127.0.0.1");

}
```

Comment: it would help if you specify what is the actual error

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to specify the port in the url if it's not the default (80):

http://localhost:3000/plumber

Second, `sleep` is not a function; and most probably it will never be the way you intend because node.js is non blocking by design.  You probably want to use something like `setTimeout`.

Comment: you are right; i didn't wrote true. localhost:3000/plumber and sleep in not a function in javascript :)

Comment: But why you advice me setTimeout ? yes, node is non blocking. isn't forking better ?